# ofstream.write writes one extra octet

Tags: c++, std, ofstream

I'm a trying to write some datas in a binary file.
Exactly, i'm writing a succession of 1 `int` and 2 `double`.

The code i'm using is the following :

```
if (with_size)
    FileStream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(const_cast<int*>
          (&this->m_)), sizeof(int));
FileStream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this->data_),
      this->m_ * sizeof(value_type));
```

The filestream is created with 
`ofstream file(file_name.c_str(), ofstream::app);`
i've tried with `ofstream::binary` to be sure but it does not change the behaviour of the bug.

Now the bug: sometimes, inside the datas, i got an extra octet. This is inside one of the double for what i've seen and never before ou after the writing.

What i'm sure of is :

- `this->m_ = 2` so
- `this->m_ * sizeof(value_type) = 16`
- `this->data_` is a valid pointer to valid values
- it doesn't happen at each writing but it happens at each run (the first time is the 3rd writing)
- it happens only on my compilation under visual c++ 2008 under windows 7,  my gcc-5.2 and 4.6 under ubuntu works perfectly fine.

Here an example of what i get (the culprit is at the end of the 3rd line ; 0d)

```
00000000: 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 e03f 0000 0000  ...........?....
00000010: 0000 e03f 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 e03f  ...?...........?
00000020: c1ca a145 b6f3 df3f 0200 0000 cd5a 0d0a  ...E...?.....Z..
00000030: 48fb ffdf 3fb5 3a39 4371 e7df 3f
```

And what i want :

```
00000000: 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 e03f 0000 0000  ...........?....
00000010: 0000 e03f 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 e03f  ...?...........?
00000020: c1ca a145 b6f3 df3f 0200 0000 cd5a 0a48  ...E...?.....Z.H
00000030: fbff df3f b53a 3943 71e7 df3f
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: You're on Windows, and you didn't specify binary mode when opening the file. Windows has the (stupid) habit to transform every 0x0a to two bytes 0x0d0a when writing it out (and vice-versa when reading) unless you tell it not to. `tried ofstream::binary` Can't believe that.

Comment: (Btw., if you want some robust serialization which works on Windows and Linux etc.etc., this is the wrong way)

Comment: You are totally right ! looks like i did not read correctly the syntaxe of ofstream ( ctor(file_name, ofstream::app,ofstream::binary) is wrong but accepted but the compilator). Thanks a lot